# Adding the results of a for loop to the same key in a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nested, tuples, key

I have a dictionary where it includes few sub-dictionaries in it. Each sub-dictionary has many keys. After running a for loop with an if condition too, the results are generated. I want to add ALL the results to under the desired key; but all what my code actually does is adding the result of the last iteration of the loop thereby replacing the value of the previous iteration.

But, actually, i want to print all the results.

```
for item in list1:          #item is a tuple & list1 has tuples in it
   if item == node_pair:        #node pair is another tuple
        high_p[i]["links"] = link_name           #"links" is the key
```

desired output:
   `"links": [link_name1, link_name2, link_name3]`
what i get:

```
"links" : link_name3
```

Please guide me..

Answer (score 0):

So each sub-dictionary needs to have lists as values. You could pre-populate each sub-dictionary with lists ahead of time, but it's easier to create them on demand using `setdefault`.

```
for item in list1:
   if item == node_pair:
        high_p[i].setdefault("links", []).append(link_name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But why does it append to the reverse order? It appends link_name3 first and link_name2 second and link_name1 last??

And also append multiples of link_name3, link_name2 and link_name1

Comment: The values should appear in the order they were added to the list. If link_name3 appears first, that means it was added to the list first. I don't have enough information about your actual program to explain why link_name3 gets iterated over before the others. Maybe if I had a [mcve]...